# Umbraco 6.2.1 with MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, umbraco, umbraco6

I am pretty much good with MVC 3 and now have been searching to integrate my application  using Umbraco CMS and I have Installed it in my solution but do not know how to integrate this and  how to Use it.

Answer (score 0):

Umbraco has a rich and helpful community.

You can refer to the following links for help:

- https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Templating/Mvc/
- https://umbraco.com/follow-us/blog-archive/2012/10/30/getting-started-with-mvc-in-umbraco-410/

The first link refers to Umbraco community on which you can ask questions and get perhaps a quicker response.